# Одинаковое отображение страницы на мобильных устройствах при портретном и ландшафтном режимах

Tags: media-queries, html, css

Добрый день!

После долгих и мучительных поисков на бескрайних просторах internet'a, после того, как все попытки узнать истину оказались тщетны, решил задать вопрос на ХэшКод'e.

Итак. Есть адаптивная верстка. В head прописано следующее:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 480px)" href="css/mobile.css" />
```

Что необходимо прописать, чтобы страница в ландшафтном режиме на мобильных устройствах отображалась также как и в портретном.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За эти режимы отвечает св-во orientation. Посмотрите готовые решения тут:
[Media Queries for Standard Devices](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Comment: @psyсho_Octopus, спасибо!
Но, том-то и вопрос ..., как все это "добро" упаковать в link и в каком порядке. Включая media для iPhone 5

Comment: А зачем вам все упаковывать в link? Вы думаете для разных устройств будут грузиться разные CSS файлы?